# How to use firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a query in the google cloud firestore to retrieve the data created in the last 10 hours, but I would like to use the server date as the basis for the account.

Something like:

```
this.afs.collection<any>("posts/", ref => {
  let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;

  tenHoursAgo = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() - 10; 
  query = query.where('created', '>', tenHoursAgo);

  return query.orderBy('created');
}).snapshotChanges()
```

How can i do this? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` as a value in a query.

Two possible workarounds for this:

1. The simplest way to get close is to use use a local current timestamp of the client: `new Date()`.
2. The more complex alternative is to have the client **write** a `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, then read that back, and use the resulting value in your query.

   This would isolate you from impact of any skew in the client's clock. Whether that is worth the extra complexity is up to you to decide.

Comment: Dates are hard, and I'm not that smart.. But maybe the real answer is that we don't need to worry about timezone when querying Firestore? Looks like Firestore stores Date objects as utc anyway (from Timestamp docs), and I would assume that the query methods would take that into account when comparing with a Date object that does have timezone information, right?