# how to get firebase time in firebase

Tags: datetime, flutter, time, google-cloud-firestore

I needed in my app firebase (server) time millisecond. because my local time will be change by mobile date time setting,

i will be see this question by not so helpful,
[Flutter Firestore Server side Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907151/flutter-firestore-server-side-timestamp)

```
var timestamp=FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

print("timestamp"+timestamp.toString());
```

but they print below value

```
====>Instance of 'FieldValue'
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
timestamp() {
    Firestore.instance.collection('timestamp').document('time').setData({
      "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }
```

Comment: but i needed in separate variable.like this                 
var timestamp=FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

Comment: First thing first don't use var because it decreases readability. if you need timestamp in a variable you can assign it outsite set data object like this:
      timestamp =  FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
and then perform whatever operation you want to perform 
and assign to timestamp variable for firestore like this
      "timestamp": timestamp,

Answer (score 1):

Before reading the timestamp you have to set it to the server since you are generating it from there. According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp())

> serverTimestamp() Returns a sentinel for use with set() or update() to include a server-generated timestamp in the written data.

so first set it

```
Firestore.instance.collection('timestamp').document('docId').setData({'time' : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

then get it using basic firestore query. Finally, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55729669/6798995) answer on the details of the why.

For more general way of getting timestamp

```
    getTimestamp() async{ 
      await Firestore.instance.collection('timestamp').document('docId').setData({'time' : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
      DocumentSnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('timestamp').document('docId').get();
      Timestamp timestamp = doc['time'];
      var timestampInMilliSeconds = timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      return timestampInMilliSeconds;
      /* here you can call setState to your own variable before returning and keep in mind this method is async so it will return a Future.  */
    }
```

Comment: i already use it,but this is set as per my mobile(device) time. not server.

Comment: ok then why don't you use FiledValue.serverTimestamp() and grab the data from firestore immediately

Comment: yes i use also this,please see my question one time more,i edited

Comment: .setData({'time' : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});   not import
and can you define direct ,how i will get in  timestamp  in separate variable.

var timeStamp="your code";

Comment: ok check the updated answer, run it and let me know if it worked for you