Fluter firebase: how to handle null exception when using FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in a query?
I tried to run the following query in Dart:
  Stream<EncountersData> getEncountersStream() {
          return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('test_encounters').where(
            'expiration_time',
            isGreaterThan:
                FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), // Same as DateTime.now()
          )
          .snapshots()
          .map(encounterDataFromSnapshot);
  }
  ... 
  // Caller
  final encounterStream = getEncountersStream();

I am getting the following error in messages.pigeon.dart:

After reading this related question, I roughly understand why the error is happening but not sure how to fix it. I tried using try-catch at every level but I am still getting the same error. I have seen example fixes using .listen instead of .map. But I would like to preserve the current code structure if possible since the caller expects the stream to be returned and is working prior to introducing FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in the filter.

You cannot use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in a query condition. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729204/how-to-use-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-in-query

Interesting. My goal here is not to to get the current time. But rather, I need to get around query limitation of security rules. In security rules, I have:
let shouldExpire = request.time > resource.data.expiration_time;   
Which always fails if I query with DateTime.now() since there's a potential of evaluating to false. I thought FieldValue.serverTimestamp()  is the key but now I'm not sure how to more forward.

Same root cause: you need to pass a literal value (that is determined client-side) to the query, and you can't resolve the server-side timestamp in the client. Best is to use an approximate timestamp and have a margin for error in either the condition or the approximation.

isGreaterThan: DateTime(2023, 10, 0, 21, 0, 0),, or changing the time to years before or after current time would cause the query to fail due to the security rule. My understanding is that because request.time and resource.data.expiration_time are both variables. Unless the query could fix one of them (e.g. FieldValue.serverTimestamp()), it's not possible to determine if all possible values of expiration_time could satisfy the rule. Love to know there are other ways to do this.
